# How to push live stream by webrtc to media server , specifically here is oven media engine?

Tags: webrtc, streaming, push

I want to push the live stream to the media server ( specifically Oven Media Engine ) from browser ( use API webrtc ) but haven't found the right way to do it , I just need WebRTC .

```js
const servers = {
    iceServers: [
      {
        urls: "turn:127.0.0.1:3478?transport=tcp",
        username: "ome",
        credential: "airen"
      }
    ]
  }; 
  
  remotePeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);
```

This code is wrong because I don't understand exactly how Webrtc API works
Look forward to the help of everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are AirenSoft, which developed OvenMediaEngine.

Your problem can be easily solved with [**OvenLiveKit for Web**](https://github.com/AirenSoft/OvenLiveKit-Web). Also, you can check the sample code by clicking [HERE](https://demo.ovenplayer.com/demo_input.html).